# DQL request from = to IN

Tags: symfony, dql

I have an issue with the IN instruction for a field...maybe you can see better than me what's happening. 
The issue is on the `waves` parameter.

I got this in my database it's a configuration field...and this field contain a json

```
{ 
 "typeId":"10,57",
 "codeVague":"ITM1702A,ITMTEST"
}
```

This request inside sql return results:

```
SELECT v.id,v.`vague_code`, v.`date_fin_ultime`,m.*

FROM Vague v

            INNER JOIN Enquete e ON e.`vague_id` = v.`id`
            INNER JOIN Mission m ON m.id = e.`mission_id`
            INNER JOIN Contrat c ON c.id = m.`contrat_id`
            INNER JOIN `User` u ON u.`enqueteur_id` = e.`enqueteur_id`
            INNER JOIN `PointDeVente` p ON p.id = e.`pdv_id`

WHERE v.`vague_code` IN ('ITM1702A','ITMTEST')
AND type_id IN (10,57)
```

But when I try to do the same from my symfony controller...I got an empty result

```
$sql="SELECT v.id,v.codeVague, v.date_fin_ultime,c.distance,p.adresse1,p.code_postal,p.ville,m
          FROM McInvestigatorBundle:Vague v
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Enquete e WITH e.vague_id = v.id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Mission m WITH m.id = e.mission_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Contrat c WITH c.id = m.contrat
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:User u WITH u.enqueteur_id = e.enqueteur_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:PointDeVente p WITH p.id = e.pdv_id
          WHERE v.codeVague IN (:waves)
                    AND e.type_id IN (:type_id)
                    AND m.enqueteur_id=:enq_id
                    ORDER BY m.date_rea_prev ASC";

    $results= $em->createQuery($sql)->setParameters([
        'waves' => $waves,
        'type_id' => $type_id,
        'enq_id' => $enq_id,
    ])->getResult();
```

The strange thing is that I got no issue with type_id, it works fine. 
But, the waves field it's not the same story....

In fact, it works only if I have only one value in the json

`"codeVague":"ITM1702A"` is working 
`"codeVague":"ITM1702A,ITMTEST"` is not working.

I already tried those strings in $waves.

`"ITM1702A,ITMTEST"` and `"'ITM1702A','ITMTEST'"` and `"'ITM1702A,ITMTEST'"`

Thanks you for your help !

EDIT: Problem solved, thanks Veve.

Comment: Try to pass an array as `codeVague` instead of a string.

Comment: The query that you called `$sql` is, in fact, written with DQL. These are different things.